# How to remove additional type parameter(s) when calling a virtual method of a two(multi)-layered generic type?

Tags: delphi, generics, overriding

There is a `TBaseClassList<T: TBaseClass>` class that has virtual method `DoSomething`. I want to call this method from another open constructed type method outside of `TBaseClassList` and its descendants called `CallDoSomething`. This is my code:

```
type
  TBaseClass = class end;

  TBaseClassList<T: TBaseClass> = class
    class procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TSubClass1 = class(TBaseClass) end;

  TSubClass1List = class(TBaseClassList<TSubClass1>)
    class procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDoSomethingCaller = class
    class procedure CallDoSomething<T: TBaseClass; L: TBaseClassList<T>>;
  end;

implementation

class procedure TSubClass1List.DoSomething;
begin
  ShowMessage('TSubClass1List.DoSomething');
end;

class procedure TDoSomethingCaller.CallDoSomething<T, L>;
begin
  L.DoSomeThing;
end;

initialization
  TDoSomethingCaller.CallDoSomething<TSubClass1, TSubClass1List>;
end.
```

Now, am I doing it in a right way? Is it possible to define `CallDoSomething` with only one type parameter?

Other definitions of `CallDoSomething` that I tried are:

**Method 1:**

```
class procedure CallDoSomething<L: TBaseClassList>;
```

My Delphi doesn't compile it (I'm using 10.1 Berlin). It says:

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TBaseClassList'

**Method 2:**

```
class procedure CallDoSomething<T: TBaseClass>;
...
class procedure TDoSomethingCaller.CallDoSomething<T>;
begin
  TBaseClassList<T>.DoSomething;
end;
```

It has a runtime error:

> Project raised exception class EAbstractError with message 'Abstract Error'.

**Method 3:**

```
class procedure CallDoSomething<L: TSubClass1List>;
```

Now I can't call `CallDoSomething` for `TSubClass2List`.

**P.S.** I didn't even know how to put my question in words, so, any suggestions for a better title or description will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you passing two Generic parameters to `CallDoSomething` if you are only using one parameter?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because I'm new in generics :). I edited my question and added what I've tried to remove the extra parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
type
  TBaseClass = class
  end;

  TBaseClassList = class
    class procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TBaseClassList<T: TBaseClass> = class(TBaseClassList)
  end;

  TSubClass1 = class(TBaseClass)
  end;

  TSubClass1List = class(TBaseClassList<TSubClass1>)
    class procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDoSomethingCaller = class
    class procedure CallDoSomething<L: TBaseClassList>;
  end;

implementation

class procedure TSubClass1List.DoSomething;
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('TSubClass1List.DoSomething');
end;

class procedure TDoSomethingCaller.CallDoSomething<L>;
begin
  L.DoSomething;
end;

initialization
  TDoSomethingCaller.CallDoSomething<TSubClass1List>;

end.
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I tried this in the first place. It doesn't compile here: `E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TBaseClassList'`. on definition of `CallDoSomething`.

Comment: Because you are missing the non generic `TBaseClassList` - at least in the code in your question.

Comment: @StefanGlienke My bad,I must read codes twice here. BTW, what is the purpose of `PTBaseClassList`?

Comment: Not needed, removed it.

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove that - It was for a possible different approach.